# Отправка через SMTP C# на Windows10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, smtp, windows-10

Написал на С# .NET (2.0) (чтоб на старых машинах работало) приложение по рассылке писем. На Windows 7 все работает исправно, перешел на Windows 10. Выдает ошибку: "Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной почты". Юзаю ящик Gmail. SMTP-порт: 587, сервак: smtp.gmail.com, SSL включен.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Имя компьютера? Как бы странно не звучало, но это важно :)

Comment: @SergeyRufanov раньше было Дмитрий-ПК на вин7, на Win10 Дмитрием-ПК и остался :)

Comment: Странно. А можете тогда глянуть в Inner Exception, у Exception'а вылетающего в студии? Там просто более подробная информация содержится.

Comment: Если там "Недопустимый знак в заголовке электронной почты." - самое вероятное, что проблема из-за русского языка/черточки в имени компьютера.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov да, так и есть! Спасибо. А как тогда исправить подобное? Ведь у многих пользователей могут быть имена ПК с кириллицей. И переименовывать ПК каждому - не вариант.

Comment: Честно - не знаю. Надо в исходниках фреймворка ковыряться, что бы выяснить точную причину. Но так у многих. В 4-м же фреймворке такой проблемы нет. Я бы просто пересобрал приложение под .NET 4.0 - [он поддерживается аж начиная с Windows XP](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=17718) (смотрите раздел "требования к системе"). Я очень сомневаюсь в том, что под "что бы на старых машинах работало" вы имели ввиду кучу работающих у вас машин с Windows 2000/ME/98 и прочими "древностями". Тем более что начиная с Windows 8, по умолчанию 2-го фреймворка в системе нет - только 4-й.

Comment: Но ведь нужно ещё "заставить" пользователя установить .NET Framework 4.*, т.к. на хрюшах его нет. А .NET 2.0 - 100% вариант. Пока с ним мучаюсь

Comment: Если у вас сеть с единой рабочей группой или доменом, то можно просто насильно поставить всем .NET 4 через групповые политики.

Answer (score 2):

Для диагностики, чтобы понять что происходит, можно включить следующий блок в раздел `<configuration>` в файл app.config

Тогда можно будет увидеть и понять что именно происходит.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="MyTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Привет. По поводу [правки описания метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51356): во-первых это копипаста с Википедии, во-вторых есть возражения по сути определения. За подробностями приходите в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 0):

Нагуглил и решил проблему XML кодом, прописав в `app.config`

`<configuration>
    <system.net>
      <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
          <network clientDomain="name"/>
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>`